# Column Sorting Dojo Enhanced Grid with JsonRestStore and ClientFilter

Tags: dojo, grid

I have defined a Dojo Enhanced Grid that uses a JsonRestStore and ClientFilter.  The data in one of the columns has string data with numbers values, for example "5201".  I've coded a formatter to change the string field to a number via parseInt(value) but when I click on that column to sort, the values are not sorted correctly because it appears that the sort is based on the store data not the formatted data. It looks like its the makeComparator method of ClientFilter that does the sorting.  Is there some way to define a sort comparators for the ClientFilter?  It looks like I need to format the data as a number in the ClientFilter comparator instead of the grid cell formatter.